# Flutter : Error Display All Item from Sqflite

Tags: sqlite, flutter, dart

[image]

I've created a button that navigating into `notes_page.dart` in my flutter project. The `notes_page.dart` contains note database using sqflite package. When I clicked the button for the first time (after I run the project), it run normally and show all of my notes. But, when I back into home page and re-open `notes_page.dart`, my notes cannot be seen and the screen just show the `CircularProgressIndicator()`

```
ElevatedButton(
                      child: Container(
                        color: Colors.teal,
                      ),
                      onPressed: () async {
                        await Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
                            builder: (context) => NotesPage()));
                      }),
```

And here is my `notes_page.dart` code :

```
class NotesPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _NotesPageState createState() => _NotesPageState();
}

class _NotesPageState extends State<NotesPage> {
  late List<Note> notes;
  bool isLoading = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    refreshNotes();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    NotesDatabase.instance.close();

    super.dispose();
  }

  Future refreshNotes() async {
    setState(() => isLoading = true);

    this.notes = await NotesDatabase.instance.readAllNotes();

    setState(() => isLoading = false);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.teal,
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(
            'Cie mau curhat ya :)',
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24),
          ),
          actions: [Icon(Icons.search), SizedBox(width: 12)],
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: isLoading
              ? CircularProgressIndicator()
              : notes.isEmpty
                  ? Text(
                      'No Notes',
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 24),
                    )
                  : buildNotes(),
        ),
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          backgroundColor: Colors.black,
          child: Icon(Icons.add),
          onPressed: () async {
            await Navigator.of(context).push(
              MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => AddEditNotePage()),
            );

            refreshNotes();
          },
        ),
      );

  Widget buildNotes() => ListView.builder(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
        itemCount: notes.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          final note = notes[index];

          return Container(
            color: Colors.transparent,
            child: GestureDetector(
              onTap: () async {
                await Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (context) => NoteDetailPage(noteId: note.id!),
                ));

                refreshNotes();
              },
              child: NoteCardWidget(note: note, index: index),
            ),
          );
        },
      );
}
```

Comment: please share your `notes_page.dart` in this question. I think the volunteer can help you when you do that. because not every one want to join that link, and not every who want to join is who can answer your question.

Comment: @GilangPratama okay thank you :)